# Would old version of mysql(5.1) caused performance issue in Django(1.11)

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm rewritting a web application using Django 1.11. When i hooked up to my test mysql database (version 5.7), the performance is amazing. The page renders within 1 second. However, when I connect to the existing production mysql (version 5.1), the page takes more than 10 seconds.

I installed the debug toolbar, and I found out the the query time is actually not the issue. Most of the time are in the CPU.

I've eliminated the possibility of mysql performance issue by directly running the query on the database. It's not network issue either since my ping is just fine.

I am wondering whether the Django is having issues with older mysql version when Django receives the data and try to map it to objects via ORM.

[image: Result from Django debug toolbar]

Comment: How did the "hooking up" take place? Did you maybe test your page on a local webserver connected to a local dev mysql server, and then just connected the local webserver to a remote prod mysql server (or are there maybe other connection issues)?

Comment: @Solarflare When i said hookup, I mean changing the database ip address in settings.py. 

Yes, I test my page from local webserver to database server A with 5.7 Mysql. Performance is great. Then I connect the same webserver to 5.1 mysql server, and the performance is very slow.

It's very unlikely network issue since ping is only 0.xxx ms.

Comment: I meant: is maybe mysql 5.7 on the same local network or even on the same server as the local webserver, while mysql 5.1 is maybe on a remote destination. Connecting to localhost instead of any other local server will make a huge difference, and connecting to a remote server will be worse.

Comment: I know what you mean. I am in the middle of setting up a mysql 5.1 in my local to isolate the possibility that you mentioned.

Comment: Following up on @Solarflare - you can (and should!) have low latency across the network, but still throwing a lot of data across the network will take longer than if the data stays within one physical server. If the query results are in the kilobyte range, no problem, but in the megabyte range the network can make a huge difference. I have written some Django queries that were quite a bit larger than expected due to all the related tables.